# Accelerating elevator?

Tags: acceleration, newtonian-gravity, equivalence-principle, reference-frames

If your in an elevator accelerating downwards faster than gravity, would you be pushed up to the ceiling? Since gravity cannot match the acceleration of the elevator, you're wouldn't be able to move at a constant velocity relative to the elevator.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Although the elevator car wouldn't be able to fall faster than gravity - you would need to have a cable pulling it down.

One of the most important principles of physics is that you can't tell if you are in a gravity field or in an accelerating box.

Answer (score 1):

yes you will be pushed up to the ceiling of elevator because you are accelerated inside the elevator due to gravity and the elevator itself is accelerated due to external faster acceleration, that makes you stuck on the elevator ceiling then they ceiling will push on you with normal force  making you move with the elevator downward