# Will we feel right up inside the airplane if the airplane accelerates toward earth at 20m/s^2?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, acceleration, free-body-diagram

Suppose you are in the airplane and the airplane falls toward the earth with acceleration of $20m/s^2$(double of gravitational acceleration $g$). This double acceleration by airplane will cancel the gravitational acceleration and create gravitational acceleration upward from the earth. If this happens, you will be pushed to the ceiling of the airplane if there is such a airplane that falls vertically from its rest position. While falling, the environment in the airplane will be the same as on the earth because in both case you will be pushed in the direction of the acceleration. My question is if this happens, will we feel right up while while being pushed to the ceiling of airplane?
Will we feel just standing on earth?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24602/

Answer (score 2):

If the plane accelerated down at 2g (ie 20m/s^2) then yes you would feel 1 gravity upward. If the plane was also upside down (!) you would feel that you were sitting in your seat normally

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the aeroplane, the acceleration will be g upward(against the earth's gravitational pull). However a person in the plane will feel weightless (till he strikes the ceiling) as there is no normal reaction of the aeroplane acting on him. There is only the gravitational force exerted on him by the earth. He won't feel as if he were standing on the earth.

Answer (score -1):

if this happens, you will be stuck to  the ceiling of the airplane but it does not mean that you are pushed up. Actually, the airplane and the person in that airplane, both are falling towards earth simultaneously but the airplane has acceleration=2g, and the person has acceleration =g. Due to this, airplane falls faster than person and ceiling of airplane will strike the person.So, person in airplane will not feel right up and he will not feel like one feels while standing on earth.

Comment: @MartinBeckett, i want your view and clarification  on this question and my answer.

Comment: @Charuhas,i want your view and clarification on this question and my answer

Comment: @annav, i want your view and clarification on this question and my answer